# Python-SQL database

Tags: python, sql, k-nn

There are two SQL databases in which one database contains user data and other database contains service data. Firstly, I am connecting the databases and fetching it on python.Based on the user data, I am recommending the services using KNN algorithm in python. I am training the user database with KNN but while recommending I wanted to use service table. The testing data is given manually through command line

Comment: Could you please ask a question- the reason for this post is unclear to me

Comment: There is no question here, just the description.

Comment: How to merge two different sql database tables in python

Comment: What library are you using for database access? Can you provide some code to illustrate the problem. Also, please clarify your question by editing it, not comments. The reason I ask you this is that people having similar issues might end up not reading the comments at all before disregarding your question.

Comment: Sorry for putting up the improper question.